# Java UDP send/receive small example does not work

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have written a small UDP client which is sending packets to a certain local address, and another small UDP client which will receive them and print on console its containt. They are not working currently, and I don't know why.

This is the sending code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClienteUDPtx {

  static final String HOST = "192.168.1.201";
  static final int PUERTO=20001;

  /**
    UDP Client which will send some UDP packets
    to local network address 192.168.1.201 on port 20001
  */
  public ClienteUDPtx( ) {
    try{
      int i = 0; 

      String[] ip_parts = HOST.split("."); 
      byte[] ip_num = {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
      for (String string : ip_parts) { 
         ip_num[i++] = Byte.valueOf(string); 
      } 

      InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip_num); 
          DatagramSocket skCliente = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO, ip);
      DatagramPacket packet;
      File testFile = new File("test.txt");
      BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(testFile));
      String line;

      while((line=input.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println("Sending: " + line);
    byte message[] = line.getBytes();
    packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, ip, PUERTO); 
        skCliente.send(packet);
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
      }
      line = "END";
      System.out.println("Sending: " + line);
      byte message[] = line.getBytes();
      packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, ip, PUERTO); 
      skCliente.send(packet);

      input.close();
      skCliente.close();
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
  }


  public static void main( String[] arg ) {
    new ClienteUDPtx();
  }

}
```

This is the receiving code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClienteUDPrx {

  static final String HOST = "192.168.1.101";
  static final int PUERTO=20001;

  /**
    UDP Client which will listen for incoming UDP packets
    from local network address 192.168.1.101 on port 20001
    and will print its content on console
  */

  public ClienteUDPrx( ) {
    try{
      int i = 0; 

      String[] ip_parts = HOST.split("."); 
      byte[] ip_num = {0, 0, 0, 0}; 
      for (String string : ip_parts) { 
         ip_num[i++] = Byte.valueOf(string); 
      } 

      InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip_num); 
      DatagramSocket skCliente = new DatagramSocket(PUERTO, ip);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);


      while(true){
        // Wait to receive a datagram
        skCliente.receive(packet);
        String lineaLeida = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
        System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "+ lineaLeida);
        if(lineaLeida.equals("END")) break; 
      }
      skCliente.close();
      System.out.println( "Transmission ended" );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
  }


  public static void main( String[] arg ) {
    new ClienteUDPrx();
  }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is 192.168.1.101 your IP address?

Comment: It is. Furthermore, I also wrote a TCP example and works like a charm, same IPs and PORT.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in here.

The first is in creating your InetAddress. Rather than trying to separate out the bytes and recreate it from an array you can just do:

```
InetAddress.getByName(HOST);
```

It fails just now because when you split HOST you are splitting it as a regular expression and using "." which has a special meaning so is isn't actually splitting the string based on the '.' character.

To actually split it on the '.' you would do:

```
HOST.split("\\.")
```

but then your byte parsing fails because bytes are in the range -128 to +127 (not 0 to 255).

Anyway, probably the reason this is confusing you is because of your error printing.

This line:

```
System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
```

is printing out the exception error (which in this case is just '0' - "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0").

Instead you should do:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to get much more info on what is going wrong.

Beyond these things I can't see any obvious issues.

I would also point out that UDP *does* check the integrity of messages.  It doesn't guarantee delivery or order of delivery so you might miss packets or get them out of sequence sometimes but it does have a checksum which includes the header + payload of the message.

Answer (score 0):

`udp` is not guarantee that packets will be **received on `other side`**.

> Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); // it's very bad if you want to receive the message

if you really wants to receive message on other side, you should to implement following logic:

1. A sends message to B;
2. if B received message from A then send message 'i received message, you can close connection'
3. A closes connection

**it's not check itegrity of message!**

possible solution is sending hash of message before message and check equality.

Comment: What's the problem about sleeping 1 second if that code is only meant to send a packet each second? If I'm not using ACKs I don't see the problem to do so.

Anyway, I understand UDP doesn't ensure communications, but if I am sending 10 packets and receiving none, into a local network scenario, I tend to think that there is something wrong with my code, which is the kind of thing I am asking for.

Anyway I like the hash idea, how would I do that?

Comment: just using `CRC32` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html

Comment: the native impl of crc32 is just horribly slow, just pointing - other than that it's an ok (as algorithm, that's it)